# AJAX Portfolio Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have decided to create a portfolio page, however I am keen to pull the page contents similar to the below:

http://demo.themezilla.com/garnish

However I would like to create a block grid and have the AJAX container, slide down (and force content down, no overlay) below the row of the selected portfolio block. I can create the hover effect and content easy however I have only ever created separate page templates not dynamically injected content.

HTML & CSS no problem. I am working on a PHP system (probably wordpress) with jQuery as a Javascript library.

I am open to suggestions which have minimal load on the server, I don't mind handing coding (attempt to) or using a plugin.

Any help and/or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: someone's already made the work for you!
http://www.themezilla.com/themes/garnish/

Comment: You could learn how to use AJAX. This would solve the problem.

Comment: While the obvious idea is helpful. I am looking for resources and some examples so that I can learn my objective.

Comment: I may not have made myself clear enough, I am looking for some direction on how to achieve the ajax effect in the link above. I am aware someone has done the work. I personally want to learn the technique not mimic / destroy other beautiful online work / items.

Answer (score 0):

In the time it would take to get a plugin to work you could build your own solution.   That would be my recommendation.